# unknown error while adding Firebase project to iOS app to download .plist file

Tags: ios, firebase, info.plist, firebase-console

I am facing this awkward problem. I am getting an unknown error while adding Firebase project to iOS app to download .plist file.

[image]

Comment: how you enter correct bundle id of the app?

Comment: @Arasuvel i have put a correct bundle id.

Comment: But I dont know why this is happening?

Comment: Please reach out to support@firebase.com as that's a firebase website error message. It's probably something simple but the support folks would be able to tell you exactly what the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a **Network Error**. I have faced this error two times but when I saw to my wifi icon it was limited, then i reconnect my wifi and pressed the button again it was done.